# 2D Ray Always hitting the GameObject it is attached to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

This Ray is always hitting the GameObject it is attached to. Even with `float.MaxValue` as distance it is hitting the GameObject it is attached to.

```
RaycastHit2D rayHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, Vector2.down, Mathf.Abs(rayTransform.position.y));
    Debug.Log (rayHit2D.transform.name);
    if (rayHit2D.transform.tag == "Platform") {
        Debug.Log ("ok");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this unity answers answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/869966/view.html). There is a setting you can change in the Physics2DSettings to have the raycast start outside the collider.

[image]